# Привязка Qt виджетов из разных потоков к общему родителю

Tags: многопоточность, qt

Нужно реализовать динамическое создание виджетов с привязкой к общему родителю. Виджеты создаются в отдельных потоках - так задано, этого не избежать.

При указании в конструкторе виджета указателя на родителя в рантайме вылетает консольное предупреждение:

> QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent,
> new parent is in a different thread

Что делать?

**Детали:**

Мне задано реализовать расширения для отображения данных, используя корпоративный фреймворк. Эти расширения должны представлять из себя динамические библиотеки (их подключением занимается фреймворк), код которых, как я предполагал, будут выполняться на контексте отдельных нитей (это опять-же контролирует фреймворк).

**P.S.**

Буду пробовать реализовать выполнение кода расширений в общем для них потоке. Вопрос наверное можно закрывать, спасибо всем отписавшим.

Comment: > так задано, этого не избежать

вы не должны работать с UI из потоков, отличных от главного.

Comment: @ASten, покажи как имеено создаются виджеты в отдельных потоках. И какая здача стоит перед тобой - тебе необходимо из потоков получить доступ к главному?

Comment: @ASten: Если создания контролов в другом потоке на самом деле не избежать, то вы проиграли, работать не должно в принципе. Скорее всего, однако, ваша программа просто плохо структурирована, и у вас модельная логика и UI-код смешаны. Отделите модель от представления, маршаллируйте данные в UI-поток, и будет вам _щасте_.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, уже задумался об этом, буду пробовать.